# I want to write a funtion printline(num,sym) that takes an integer num and a symbol sym as parameters and prints a line with sym repeated num times

Tags: python

Here is the example: printline(10,'*') will print the pattern below:

```
************
```

And below is my work

```
def printline(num,sym):
    for i in range(num):
        a = (num*'sym')
a = printline(5,'*')
print(a)
```

My work output is None. Anyone can help me fix it?

Comment: Your function does not have a return statement. Therefore it returns None.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you!

Comment: You also don't need the for loop, if you want the example pattern then just change your function definition to return num*sym

Comment: I’m voting to close this as typo/can’t reproduce, since the only issue was a missing return statement.

Answer (score -1):

First of all on line 3
 `a = (num*'sym')`
sym should not be a string because you are referencing the variable sym
from line 1
`def printline(num,sym)`
and second of all below you need to return a value, this value will be a since thats the
value you want to print.
So the code should look like:

```
def printline(num,sym):
    for i in range(num):
        a = (num*sym)
        return a
a = printline(5,'*')
print(a)
```

The output would then be:

```
*****
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the for-loop in this answer? i is not used and it will always immediately return num*sym